# strange behavior with java script in internet explorer .It is working in chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
{
var x=document.getElementsByName("first");

alert(x.length);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<h1 name="first">hi</h1>

<form>
uname:<input type="text" name="first" value="sree"> <br>

password:<input type="password" name="first" value="dhar">
<p name="first">hello</p>


<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many elements named 'x'?">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this code.The alert is showing `4` in `chrome`.But in `ie` it is showing `2`.What might be the reason.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Shows 4 for me in IE9/10...

Comment: Editplus has built in browser as ie.It is not working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 only recognizes the `name` attribute on the `<input>`s. Use a class instead.
Fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ChpCr/
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ChpCr/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute is **[not](http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-name-attribute.php)** actually a valid attribute for `h1` or `p` elements.

It is however, valid for the two input elements, so that is probably why it is returning `2`.

Comment: then what about remaining browsers

Comment: @PSR Well.. IE8 and before have a lot of weird behaviour compared to most other browsers, I can't explain why they handle things so differently in this case, but it makes sense that they don't pick up on an invalid attribute.